# Java Graphics.drawLine() inexact: drawn lines are too long

Tags: java, graphics, line

I have a polygon with the vertices (0,0), (100,0), (100,100), and (0,100).
I debugged the program and those are the exact lines that java is drawing.
Instead of drawing an exact square, some of the lines are a pixel too long:
http://gyazo.com/7418546c51c9a10fc690b18afcc96360.png
(The green circle is just me testing the centroid).
When I move the square out of the corner, you can see that the top left corner is the only corner that is exactly correct.
Why is this happening?
Right before drawLine, I wrote the lines to the console after they were converted to integer coordinates, and they were correct. So I can't see what could possibly be wrong except for the drawLine functions.
drawLine:

```
        g.drawLine((int) line.getStart().getX(), (int) line.getStart().getY(), 
            (int) line.getEnd().getX(), (int) line.getEnd().getY());
```

The line has a start vector and an end vector. The vectors contain an x and y.

Even when doing this:

```
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 0);
    g.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 100);
    g.drawLine(100, 100, 0, 100);
    g.drawLine(0, 100, 0, 0);
```

It still produces the same result.
This works though:

```
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 0);
    g.drawLine(101, 0, 101, 100);
    g.drawLine(100, 101, 0, 101);
    g.drawLine(0, 100, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please post your code.  It's probably an off by one thing, but it's hard to say without seeing some code.

Comment: Please provide the source code...

Comment: Well we need to see how you called the method. Please provide a *minimal working example*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you provided is working:

```
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.translate(50, 50);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 0);
    g.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 100);
    g.drawLine(100, 100, 0, 100);
    g.drawLine(0, 100, 0, 0);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(bi));
```

---

There is a bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049901 that describes one possible issue.

Comment: This is it. What does disabling java2D D3D do though?